# I cannot get ckeditor up and running on existing code that actually has to work

Tags: ckeditor

Every custom build I have created failed to run with either "Uncaught TypeError: a.addContentsCss is not a function" or some similar complaint -- I've tried dozens of custom builds. There must be some dependencies that are not enforced by the configurator. Reluctantly, I went to using a FULL build, modified by the `config.js`. The config.js was ignored, even when I specified a custom path to it. It was only honored when it was done inline. Even at this point I was still left with the editor either not recognizing input via `myField.value = "something"`, and or not returning anything from `myField.value` when marshalling input to send to the back end. Clearly, there is something obvious that I am missing here. Help?

Create a single-page app with plain *javascript*, *jQuery*, *jQuery UI*, *ckeditor 4.x*, latest version of all of the above, and no "framework".

Create a custom build of ckeditor corresponding to the following:

```
{
toolbarGroups : [
{ name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
{ name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
{ name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker', 'editing' ] },
{ name: 'forms', groups: [ 'forms' ] },
{ name: 'tools', groups: [ 'tools' ] },
'/',
{ name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
{ name: 'colors', groups: [ 'colors' ] },
'/',
{ name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi', 'paragraph' ] },
{ name: 'insert', groups: [ 'insert' ] },
{ name: 'links', groups: [ 'links' ] },
'/',
{ name: 'styles', groups: [ 'styles' ] },
'/',
{ name: 'others', groups: [ 'others' ] },
{ name: 'about', groups: [ 'about' ] }
],
removeButtons : 
'Source,Save,NewPage,Preview,Print,Templates,SelectAll,Form,Checkbox,' +
'Radio,TextField,Textarea,Select,Button,ImageButton,HiddenField,' +
'CreateDiv,Blockquote,Language,BidiRtl,BidiLtr,Anchor,Image,Flash,' +
'PageBreak,ShowBlocks,About'
}
```

Run code with one instance of `CKEDITOR.replace("sometextareaid");` and get one of the following errors, depending on which of a million custom builds or full builds you have spent hours trying:
a. config is ignored unless it is placed inline -- config.js appears to go unread, even if you set a custom url for it.
b. looks fine, but data inserted programmatically (`myTextara.value = "some words";`) does not show up.
c. looks fine, shows data that was already previously present in the textarea, but additional user input comes back as "" when you try to send someField.value to send to the backend.
d. fails to run, saying something or another is not a function of something else, varying by custom build. Seems like a dependency violation, but no indication of which thing I included needs what thing I did not include.

Anything this broken is usually the result of something dumb and obvious to those in the know. What am I missing?

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: Sorry for this question, but did you tried to reload your browser cache ?

Comment: Yes, the cache has been cleared.

Comment: There is also possibility that config.js is ignored, because it has syntax or configuration error in it.

Comment: Thnks -- the config.js was generated and not hand-edited.